# I can't build dlib library on xcode

Tags: ios, swiftui

I'm trying to use dlib in ios so I can run an application using face recognition

I'm following [this link](https://medium.com/@prabhu_irl/getting-started-with-dlib-on-ios-5e66d77380d) to build dlib for ios then the error below shows up.

```
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "_USER_ERROR__missing_dlib_all_source_cpp_file__OR__inconsistent_use_of_DEBUG_or_ENABLE_ASSERTS_preprocessor_directives_", referenced from:
      _dlib_check_consistent_assert_usage in DlibWrapper.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

My environment

Mac (OSX) Catalina 10.15.4

SwiftUI (working with)

XCode 11.4

iPhone 6S

IOS 13.4.1

Comment: Hi. Sorry to be the bearer of bad news, but unless you have a more modern device, you won't be able to work with face recognition. You don't have the cameras you need on devices lower than the iPhone X.

Comment: @Mozahler Is there a relation between camera device and dlib library? originally dlib is not for ios so I knew that I can grab frames from camera using native interface and then dlib helps just processing frames

Comment: I don't understand your new question. Yes there's a relation between the library and the hardware it supports. I downloaded the sample project and it won't compile for the simulator. That's because the dlib that was included in the project wasn't compiled for the simulator architecture so that's a dead end -- unless you can build dlib yourself or get a copy with the appropriate architecture. Apple's native libraries process frames, look into them. AVFoundation Photos/PhotosUI, etc. Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

I'm afraid your title is a little misleading. You're not trying to build a library - you've downloaded a precompiled library and are trying to use it in a way it wasn't meant to be used.  The library in question was not built for Intel architecture, so it won't run on the simulator. You have a number of options on how to proceed:

- You can look for binaries with the appropriate architecture
- Find the source code to the library (perhaps in a git project) and compile the libraries yourself

or look into Apple's Machine Learning Libraries and Technologies

https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/209/
https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2018/703/

Check out these and other WWDC videos on machine learning and ARKit as a starter.

I recommend you download Apple's own `Developer` app from the App Store.

https://apps.apple.com/us/app/apple-developer/id640199958

[image]

You can use it to find many videos on available resources.

There are a number of **very powerful tools** available.  It helps if you know python, since that's where a lot of the development work is happening.

Maybe it would help if you were to look into how things are done in the iOS environment so you can better understand how it relates to other platforms. 
There are many helpful articles out there, this is the first one I found:

https://towardsdatascience.com/core-machine-learning-for-ios-developers-7f2a4b19ec08

The key is to not get discouraged! There's a lot of useful information out there and it's important to look for alternatives when you've gone down a dead end.

Good Luck!